# Функция file_get_contents в c++

Tags: http, парсер, c++, get

Если такая функция в c++ ?

Просто хочу переписать

```
function Parser_url($url){
$test = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET",'header'=>"User-Agent: TEST\r\n"));
$create = stream_context_create($test);
$parser = file_get_contents($url, false, $create);}
```

с php на c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сбегал в [аналогичный вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912520/read-file-contents-into-a-string-in-c), вот краткий обзор вариантов:

Если подойдет `std::filebuf`, то это самый быстрый вариант [предложил](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2912602/116546) [Котик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4149/):

```
std::ifstream file(filename);
std::streambuf* content = file.rdbuf();
```

Если хочется `std::string`, то как-то так:

```
std::ifstream file(filename);
std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file) ),
                     (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()     ) );
```

Аналогичным образом можно засунуть и в `std::vector<char>`.

Ну и если нужен `char*`, то:

```
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");

// Получаем размер файла
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t size = ftell(f);

// Выделяем память, читаем данные
char* content = new char[size]; // Или (char *)malloc(size), тогда будет чистый C.
rewind(f);
fread(where, sizeof(char), size, f);
```

**НО:** это все для файлов в локальной файловой системе. Для HTTP же можно обойтись [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/iostreams.html) с чем-то в духе

```
ip::tcp::iostream stream;
stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
stream.connect("www.boost.org", "http");
stream << "GET /LICENSE_1_0.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n";
stream << "Host: www.boost.org\r\n";
stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
stream.flush();
std::streambuf* content = stream.rdbuf();
```

Или использовать, например, [Urdl](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/urdl/reference/core/istream.html):

```
urdl::istream stream("http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt");
std::streambuf* content = stream.rdbuf();
```

Или использовать [libcurl](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/45878/) (по ссылке есть примеры).

Comment: спс все ра6отает =)

Answer (score 4):

Нет такой функции в стандартных библиотеках и STL. Вот [здесь](http://2lx.ru/2010/06/file_get_contents-dlya-c-v2/) лежит код, но его не проверял.

1. У вас файл, который вы хотите получить, уже лежит на накопителе?
2. В какой тип данных вы хотите получить содержимое файла `(std::string , char *)`?

Проверил у себя работает. Примеры ниже.

```
#include <fstream>

static int file_get_contents(std::string file_name, char *&content_file, long long &size_file)
{
    if (file_name.empty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    std::fstream reader(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!reader) {
        std::cout << "n Файл не существует или его невозможно открыть на чтение! - " << file_name;
        return -2;
    }
    reader.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_file = reader.tellg();
    reader.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    content_file = new char[size_file];
    reader.read(content_file, size_file);
    reader.close();
    if (size_file == 0) {
        return -3;
    }

    content_file[size_file] = 0;
    return 1;
}

//// Примеры.
//
// применение
char * content = 0;
long long size = 0;
file_get_contents("файл.txt", content, size);
std::cout << "\nсодержимое 1=" << content;

// Для std::string
std::string text;
char * content2;
size = 0;
file_get_contents("файл.txt", content2, size);
text.append(content2, size);
std::cout << "\nсодержимое 2=" << text;
```